Getting dozens of warnings running a Windows project on Windows
I have a class library. I've specified that it is targeting .NET on Windows in the project file.
<PropertyGroup>
  <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  <TargetFramework>net9.0-windows</TargetFramework>
  <Platform>windows</Platform>
  <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
  <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  <AllowUnsafeBlocks>true</AllowUnsafeBlocks>
</PropertyGroup>

But I get dozens of warnings similar to this.

This call site is reachable on all platforms. 'Form.ShowDialog()' is only supported on: 'windows' 6.1 and later.

I know I can add [SupportedOSPlatform("windows")]  on every single method, but why should I need to do this? I've specified my target is Windows. How can I get it to work on Windows?

What Windows version are you using?

@DanielA.White: Windows 11 Home 24H2. Why? What would that affect?

You've tagged asp.net-core. Why are you using Form.ShowDialog in an ASP.NET project?

Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1416#tfm-target-platforms

@KlausGütter: Yes, actually, setting GenerateAssemblyInfo to true seems to have eliminated this particular warning.
